# jQuery UI, draggable child div larger than parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, parent

I have looked over several articles and tried all of the methods proposed and found no solutions as of yet.

I am attempting to create a map that is draggable, but will stop when it its own edge meets the edge of the parent's edge. The child is larger than the parent so I have tried all different types of methods to resolve this but have yet to find a solution.

The example below shows an example in which the black border should not have any white space within. I have tried containment in several different flavors but haven't figured out the math for it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LQtCY/3/

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have u tried this?

```
var parentPos = $('.mapshell').offset();
var childPos = $('.mapcontent_1').offset();

$(".mapcontent_1").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.top > parentPos.top) {
            ui.position.top = parentPos.top;
        }
        if (ui.position.left > parentPos.left) {
            ui.position.left = parentPos.left;
        }
    },

    scroll: false
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LQtCY/6/

Comment: How can I get it to stop when the edges of the child meet the parent. I don't want there to be an empty space within the black box: http://jsfiddle.net/LQtCY/3/

Comment: I don't mind the child going outside of the black line as long as it does go past 1 pixel inside if that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks, I got the left and top sides working correctly, just need to add the right and bottom.

Comment: That wasn't quite the full solution, but definitely pointed me in the right direction...thnx!

Comment: Shouldn`t it be offset instead of position of UI object?